# Member Access Design (Accessing a member of a member)

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am wondering if anyone has a design that can help me edit nested objects from a GUI interface.

Lets say I have two classes

```
class ObjectA
{
    public:
       ObjectA()
       ~ObjectA()

       unsigned GetParam();
       void SetParam(unsigned Param)

    private:
      unsigned Param;
};

class ObjectB
{
    public:
       ObjectB()
       ~ObjectB()

       ObjectA GetObjectA();
       void SetObjectA(ObjectA ObjA)

    private:
      ObjectA ObjA;
};
```

Now Suppose I have access to ObjectB but I really need to set Param from the GUI. There are two ways I can see to do this.

1. Use accessors and mutators to edit the object

   ```
   ObjectA ObjA = ObjB.GetObjectA();
   ObjA.SetParam(100);
   ObjB.SetObjectA(ObjA);
   ```
2. Add a public interface to ObjectB

   ```
   void ObjectB::SetParam(unsigned Param)
   {
       ObjA.SetParam(Param);
   }
   ```

I really don't like these solutions because they involve a lot a code writing do access object parameters and don't scale well. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you return the object as a reference in alternative one, then you can use `ObjB.GetObjectA().SetParam(100);`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to make the objA as a pointer rather than an object itself since it will make easier to avoid dealing with copy constructor and moreover if there are more functions inside ObjectA then you may need to have same functions in class ObjectB eg: like SetParam you may need to implement GetParam..

The functions are responsibility of the respective classes and not the responsibility of the container class.

```
class ObjectA
{
    public:
       ObjectA()
       ~ObjectA()

       unsigned GetParam();
       void SetParam(unsigned Param)

    private:
      unsigned Param;
};

class ObjectB
{
    public:
       ObjectB()
       ~ObjectB()

       ObjectA* GetObjectA();
       void SetObjectA(ObjectA *ObjA)

    private:
      ObjectA *ObjA;
};



ObjectA *ObjA = ObjB.GetObjectA();
ObjA->SetParam(100);
```

Comment: What is the intent of making `ObjA`, `private` if you just want to expose it through a `public` method? It is just as good as keeping it `public`.

Comment: making public then allows you to delete, new  without any restrictions. Making it private allows some level of control for the container class in terms of its lifetime

Comment: I agree your solution is nice to deal with copy constructor issues. What scares me is anyone using my class now has access to non const data which can be changed without my class knowing about it.

I guess had been hoping there was a design pattern out there I was unaware of that people use to access data in editors. Maybe wishful thinking.

Comment: @MSTEVENS rightly said, the whole point is unless you know the exact relationship and responsiblites of both the classes we cannot come to a conclusion. Design varies based on context